# Unable to trigger a build through command

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am calling this command as a prebuild event from one of the project

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tfsbuild" start "tfs-server" "project name" "Build definition name"

Error:
Microsoft (R) TfsBuild Version 10.0.0.0
for Microsoft Visual Studio v10.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

TF215036: The build request cannot be queued at or below position 1 on build con
troller Euphrates. The resulting position would be 2.

On tfs their is not a single build running

Please help
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at this post, they have the same problem, maybe it could help you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2007/05/16/visual-studio-2005-client-starting-builds-on-an-orcas-server-and-build-machine.aspx

or

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/0b37237c-c485-4667-8829-1da92e464546

Comment: I checked these posts but the thing is that i checked my tfs and their is no build that is running. The second post tells that add /queue to the command but this this causes it to return immediately that i dont want..

Comment: I have a build definition that will build a solution and the solution contains 3 projects.From one project i am calling this command as pre-build event.so when i am triggering the build definition this command will run. At this time i got that error

Comment: I can not understand why you are doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply....But its hard to explain why i am doing this...i need to trigger a build from a a build..

Comment: this is the answer to your question, you can not start another build from a build. When Tfs said that is another build running is making reference to your project build who stated the solution build.